# Class Array Defining

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I cannot seem to work out how to populate a sub class...

These are the classes I have:

```
public class Item
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Items[] objects { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public object next { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public object previous { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public Additionalprices additionalPrices { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public int categoryPosition { get; set; }
    public string cdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ctime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ctimeOnServer { get; set; }
    public Dimensions dimensions { get; set; }
    public string entityType { get; set; }
    public object imageURL { get; set; }
    public object[] imageURLs { get; set; }
    public string longDesc { get; set; }
    public string manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int minQty { get; set; }
    public DateTime mtime { get; set; }
    public DateTime mtimeOnServer { get; set; }
    public int multQty { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int objID { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string resource_uri { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public object thumbnailURL { get; set; }
    public object[] thumbnailURLs { get; set; }
    public string unitPrice { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public Variant[] variants { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add some dummy objects...

This is the code I have...

```
// Create a dummy Category
HandShake_Classes.Category categoryToUpload = new HandShake_Classes.Category();

categoryToUpload.name = "Trev Category";

// Create a dummy Item
HandShake_Classes.Item itemToUpload = new HandShake_Classes.Item();

// THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS...
itemToUpload.objects = new HandShake_Classes.Items();
// THE ERROR I AM GETTING IS Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'handshake.com.HandShake_Classes.Items' to 'handshake.com.HandShake_Classes.Items[]'

// Only populate required fields at the moment
itemToUpload.objects[0].sku = "ljklj";
itemToUpload.objects[0].name = "Trevs Product";
itemToUpload.objects[0].unitPrice = "1.23";
itemToUpload.objects[0].minQty = 1;
itemToUpload.objects[0].category = categoryToUpload;
```

I just cannot work out how define the Items[] I *think*

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Since you have defined the Items object as an Array, you must instantiate it like in th answers below. I would, however, suggest you to change it to a List<Items>. It might provide much more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the array first. Let's say you need 10 items:

```
itemToUpload.objects = new HandShake_Classes.Items[10];
```

And then you can set every array item to the new `Items()` instance:

```
itemToUpload.objects[0] = new HandShake_Classes.Items();
itemToUpload.objects[0].sku = "ljklj";
itemToUpload.objects[0].name = "Trevs Product";
itemToUpload.objects[0].unitPrice = "1.23";
itemToUpload.objects[0].minQty = 1;
itemToUpload.objects[0].category = categoryToUpload;
```

And just to make it clear: if you don't know how many items `object` property will have to handle, you should consider changing it to `List<Items>` instead of `Items[]` array:

```
itemToUpload.objects = new List<HandShake_Classes.Items>();

var newItem = new HandShake_Classes.Items();
newItem = new HandShake_Classes.Items();
newItem.sku = "ljklj";
newItem.name = "Trevs Product";
newItem.unitPrice = "1.23";
newItem.minQty = 1;
newItem.category = categoryToUpload;

itemToUpload.objects.Add(newItem);
```

Comment: thanks - I agree and have changed it to List<Items> - what should I do now to initialise it please?

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the array of type items as

`itemToUpload.objects = new HandShake_Classes.Items[10];`

After this instantiation, you would require to instantiate every index of the object.

For example

`itemToUpload.objects[i] = new HandShake_Classes.Items();`

This means you are instantiating a single object, and that object would be in array at index 'i'.

you can then set the properties of the `Items` in objects array by writing as

`itemToUpload.objects[i].barcode`

even call the functions

`itemToUpload.objects[i].CalculateTax()`

similarly you can use any constructors if defined.